# how to retrieve a value from an userform

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet, audit-trail

I'm trying to write a code to trace every change made by the user on any worksheet. The user will input data and from time to time will erase said data and/or correct the original value they inserted. If the change is either deletion or modification, an Userform will pop up and the user will include a reason for that change. Right now I'm able to display the form everytime the user makes one of the changes mentioned before, but I'm not able to retrieve the reason, could you guys help me?

This is what I have for the UserForm

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim msgvalue As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim value As String
msgvalue = MsgBox("Do you wish to save the change?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirm")
    If msgvalue = vbNo Then GoTo Command 
    If msgvalue = vbYes Then
        value = UserForm1.txtCmmt.Value
        If value = "" Then GoTo Command
        End
    End If
Command:
MsgBox ("A reason must be provided")
    With UserForm1
        .txtCmmt.Value = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

So if a user tries to delete a value, the code is the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Dim sLastAction As String
Dim Cell As Range
sLastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
For Each Cell In Target
    If sLastAction = "Clear" Or sLastAction = "Delete" Or Left(sLastAction, 9) = "Typing ''" Then
       
        UserForm1.Show 'this is where I'm stuck, I'm not sure how to retrieve the value from the form
    End If
'the code continues to retrieve other info from the changes made, including the "reason"
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should say **where** do you want the data to be retrieved... Only after that we can see how to help you in retrieving it.

Comment: Right after `UserForm1.Show` you can add a line of code similar to `x = UserForm1.txtCmmt.Value`.

Comment: i've tried what @BrianMStafford suggested and the value is still not retrieved correctly

Comment: @Brian M Stafford: I am afraid that in that specific moment `x` will be nothing. The form will be loaded by the event, but something from its text box should be retrieved **only after the operator fills something in this one**. The question remains (for me), where the data to be retrieved... It can be done using a button, closing the form, using a the text box event etc., but where to be retrieved... I mean, to be written in a cell, in a log file, in a comment, where to be retrieved?

Comment: @FaneDuru You are correct.  I overlooked the fact the OP did not actually create a new instance of the form.  If they had my code would have worked fine.  Also, does it really matter where the data is going to?  You still need to retrieve the data somehow.

Comment: @FaneDuru whenever a change is detected, the data (original value, user, date and time, etc.) will be retrieved and included in a designated sheet. This command is included in the Workbook_SheetChange sub: ```If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Value = comment
'the rest of the data is also determined here
Application.EnableEvents=True
End If
End Sub```

Comment: " comment" is the variable the user types in the form ("reason")

Comment: And how do you expect to deal with that 'comment' during the event code execution, since this variable **did not yet receive a value**? Do you expect that the event code will wait for the text box in the form to be filled and will take its value when it will be somehow informed that the comment has been done? The code only loads the form and continues to the next code lines. You must do it from the form itself! When do you need the text to be logged in that specific sheet? Pressing a button, typing Enter, closing the form? You mult imagine a way to trigger that retrieving...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

1. Let us say that your text box where the comment will be written is named "txtComment".
2. Put this code in its `Exit` event:

```
Private Sub txtComment_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
 If Me.txtComment.text <> "" Then
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
         Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Value = Me.txtComment.text
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Unload Me
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Let the existing Worksheet_Change event as it is, only launching the form and maybe making a `Public` boolean variable (from a standard module) `True` (something `boolStop`) which will not allow changing anything in any worksheet until it is not `False`.

Then fill the text you need in the text box ("txtComment", or however you named it) and press `Enter`. If my above suggestion looks interesting for you, the last line of the text box event will be `boolStop = False`.

If you understand how to implement the above simple solution, you maybe will forget about a user form and use a simple `InputBox`, as in the next example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) <> "E1" Then Exit Sub
    Dim sLastAction As String, comValue As String
    Dim Cell As Range
    sLastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").list(1)
    For Each Cell In Target
        If sLastAction = "Clear" Or sLastAction = "Delete" Or left(sLastAction, 9) = "Typing ''" Then
WritePlease:
            comValue = InputBox("Please write the reason for cell """ & Cell.Address & """ (" & sLastAction & ").", "Reason, please")
              If comValue = "" Then GoTo WritePlease
              If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
                  Application.EnableEvents = False
                    'Stop
                   Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Value = comValue
                  Application.EnableEvents = True
              End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! It worked perfectly for my code, I am now getting the value back

Comment: @alexmso Glad I could help! What variant did you use?

Comment: I used the second one and only included the rest of the variables I needed. Thanks again!!